# React and TypeScript: Give Parameter to onClick EventHandler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add TypeScript to my React-Todo app and got the following problem.
In my Todo component, on a button, I call the event handler: handleStatus via an onCLick function.

```
<Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index])  }  />
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as I want to give this handler a Todo as an argument, I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in src/components/Todo.tsx:29:84
TS2345: Argument of type 'Todos' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
  Type 'Todos' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 29 more.
    27 |             <div className= { className } key={ todos[index].id.toString() }>
    28 |                 {todos[index].describtion}
  > 29 |                 <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index])  }  />
       |                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    30 |                 
    31 |             </div>
    32 |         </>
```

This handler changes a specific todo so I have to give it a todo as a parameter. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the Full Code:

TodoTable (Parent)

```
interface TodoTableProps {
    mockTodos: Array<Todos>
}


let currentTodos: Todos  [];  

export const TodoTable: FunctionComponent<TodoTableProps> = ({ mockTodos }): ReactElement => {
    //Data input
    if(mockTodos){
        currentTodos = mockTodos;
    }
   
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Array<Todos>>(currentTodos);   
     
  
    //Create Todo handler
    const handleCreateTodo = (): void => {

        //create new Todo
        const newTodo = {
            //id: todos.length+1,
            id: v4(),
            describtion: enterTodo,
            done: false
        };
     
        setTodos((todos: Array<Todos>) => 
            [
                newTodo,
                ...todos
            ]
        );
        setEnterTodo('');
        
        
    };

   

    //Status handler
    const handleStatus = (event: Todos): void => {
        
        const newStatus = event.done == true ? false : true;
        const newTodos = [ ...todos];
       
        newTodos.forEach((element, index) => {
            if(newTodos[index].id == event.id){
                newTodos[index].done = newStatus;                
            }
        });
        
        setTodos(newTodos);
    }
  
  
    return(
            <>
                <InputBar 
                    enterTodo={ enterTodo } 
                    handleEnterTodo={ handleEnterTodo } 
                    handleCreateTodo={ handleCreateTodo }
                />
                
                <TodosDisplay 
                    todos={ todos } 

                    handleStatus={ handleStatus }
                /> 
            </>      
    );
}
```

TodoDisplay (Child)

```
interface TodosDisplayProps {
    todos: Array<Todos>,
    handleDeleteTodo: MouseEventHandler,
    handleStatus: MouseEventHandler
}

export const TodosDisplay: FunctionComponent<TodosDisplayProps> = ({ todos, handleDeleteTodo, handleStatus }): ReactElement => {

    
    
    return(
        <>
            {todos.map((element: Todos, index: number) => {
                
                if(todos[index].done == false){
                    return(
                        <Todo
                            key={ todos[index].id.toString() }  
                            todos={ todos } 
                            handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                            handleStatus={ handleStatus} 
                            index={ index } 
                            className= "openTodos" 
                        />  
                    );                  
                } 
            })
            }
            {todos.map((element: Todos, index: number) => {
                
                if(todos[index].done == true){                    
                    return(
                        <Todo
                            key={ todos[index].id.toString() } 
                            todos={ todos } 
                            handleDeleteTodo={ handleDeleteTodo } 
                            handleStatus={ handleStatus} 
                            index={ index } 
                            className= "doneTodos" 
                        />   
                    );                   
                }
                
            })
            } 
        </>
    );
}
```

Component: Todo

```
interface TodoProps {
    
    todos: Array<Todos>
    
    handleStatus: MouseEventHandler,
    handleDeleteTodo: MouseEventHandler,
    index: number,
    className: string

}

export const Todo: FunctionComponent<TodoProps> = ({ todos, handleDeleteTodo, handleStatus, index, className }): ReactElement => {

   
    const d_todo: Todos = todos[index];
    

    return(
        <> 
            <div className= { className } key={ todos[index].id.toString() }>
                {todos[index].describtion}
                <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index])  }  />
                
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Component: Button

```
interface ButtonProps {
    lable: string,
    disabled: boolean,
    onClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>    
}

export const Button: FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = ({ lable, disabled, onClick}): ReactElement => {
    
    return(
        <button type='button' disabled= { disabled } onClick= { onClick }>
                {lable}
        </button>
    );
}
```

I think the mistake is in the definition of the hanleStatus. If I change the type of handleStatus to "any" in the interface TodoProps, the error disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think your instinct is correct.  `handleStatus()` is not a `MouseEventHandler` -- if it were, its parameter would be of type `MouseEventArgs`.  Your mouse event handler is the arrow function which *calls* `handleStatus()`.

But I would declare the type of `handleStatus()` as `(Todos) => void` rather than `any`.